# How to center a Navbar that is 90% of the screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, uinavigationbar

I want to center the navbar as a whole, not the contents of the nav bar.

This is the `CSS` and `HTML` for my navbar.

```css
.navbar {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 30px 30px;
  background: #3CE18F;
  overflow: visible;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 3%;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed bottom</a>
</nav>
```

I've tried centering using css & using class names to center but it always seems to left align. I want it perfectly centered.

See attached image for what's going wrong.

[image: Nav Bar Image]

As you can see the nav bar is forced left.
I don't want to use padding as that can vary for different screen sizes.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use bootstrap class mx-auto

Comment: Try adding `m-auto` class to your navbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap you nav inside a div and add property justify-content to align it horizonatally:

```
<div class="wrapper"><nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed bottom</a>
</nav></div>

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add display: block and margin: auto to the navbar. Add display: flex to the parent element of the navbar. Should work.

Comment: Just tested that and it didn't work.